# OpenThread returns same handle for different threads ID

Tags: winapi

Using the following code taken from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/02/23/537856.aspx) with some additions to get thread handles, `OpenThread` returns the same handle but different ID for each thread in a process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 HANDLE h = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
 HANDLE hThread;
 if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  THREADENTRY32 te;
  te.dwSize = sizeof(te);
  if (Thread32First(h, &te)) {
   do {
     if (te.dwSize >= FIELD_OFFSET(THREADENTRY32, th32OwnerProcessID) +
                      sizeof(te.th32OwnerProcessID)) {
       hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, te.th32ThreadID);
       printf("Process 0x%04x Thread 0x%04x Handle %d\n",
             te.th32OwnerProcessID, te.th32ThreadID, hThread);
       CloseHandle(hThread);
     }
   te.dwSize = sizeof(te);
   } while (Thread32Next(h, &te));
  }
  CloseHandle(h);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Some output:

```
Process 0x10fc Thread 0x2270 Handle 68
Process 0x10fc Thread 0x13d4 Handle 68
Process 0x10fc Thread 0x071c Handle 68
Process 0x10fc Thread 0x2140 Handle 68
Process 0x10fc Thread 0x20d4 Handle 68
Process 0x1b70 Thread 0x21e8 Handle 68
Process 0x1c7c Thread 0x1d18 Handle 68
Process 0x1c7c Thread 0x10b8 Handle 68
Process 0x0d84 Thread 0x1fa0 Handle 68
```

So how am I supposed to use functions which needs a thread handle if all of them have the same number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to keep a handle to the thread, don't close the handle!

Comment: That makes sense :lol: Thought that the handle was unique. Thanks buddy!

Comment: The handle is only unique during its lifetime. Once it's closed, it's ordinal can be reused.